# Scraping earnings dates from ychart.com

Tags: python, web-scraping

[image]

I need the historical earnings dates, so I'm trying to **scrape** them from ychart.com.
I tried to **scrape** earnings dates for APPLE stock(in the table appears in the uploaded picture) using the script below,

```
import requests

url = 'https://ycharts.com/companies/AAPL/events/#/?eventTypes=earnings,&pageNum=1'

page = requests.get(url)
page_content = page.content
with open('data.txt', 'w') as f: 
    f.write(page_content) 
    f.close()
```

I save 'page_content' into a text file and search for the earnings dates, but I didn't find any of them!

Comment: So what's in the text file? How do you write the text file?

Comment: with open('data.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(page_content)
        f.close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the data from that page you need to use selenium in combination with python because the data from that page are getting generated dynamically. However, to grab the content from that page, you can do something like below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://ycharts.com/companies/AAPL/events/#/?eventTypes=earnings,&pageNum=1")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")
driver.quit()
for item in soup.find_all(class_="colDate"):
    print(item.text)
```

Partial Result:

```
Time
08/01/2017 
05/02/2017 
01/31/2017
```

Comment: If it works then don't forget to mark it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: A chrome page is opened and closed when getting the data, can I get the data without opening this page? because I have too many stocks to get their dates, and I will run the code on ssh server, if this page will open for each stock, it will be very very slow.

Comment: Yeah that is possible if you go for the headless browsing option. Chrome has recently released that version and there is another known as `phantomjs`. However, the way you did it is the most used and favorite way of doing stuffs using selenium. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you did with your script is getting the HTML from the web page.
Now you need to parse the HTML to get the data you want.
You can use the lxml library or beautifulsoup or even scrapy to do some web scraping.

```
from lxml import html
import requests

url = 'https://ycharts.com/companies/AAPL/events/#/?eventTypes=earnings,&pageNum=1'

page = requests.get(url)
page_content = page.content

tree = html.fromstring(page_content)
my_xpath = '//th[@class="colDate ng-binding"]/text()'
dates = tree.xpath(my_xpath)

for date in dates:
    print("{}".format(date))
```

And you should end up with a list of dates in "dates".

EDIT : You are not getting anything executing this script because request.get() retrieves the HTML without it being modified by Javascript, the table is created and filled by the Javascript.

My answer is not working for this problem, it is just a basic web scraping script.

Comment: I don't know the right  answer, but this script returns empty in my computer. Size of "dates" list is 0.

Comment: @Alperen debug it with some breakpoints or run it line by line in `ipython` to see what the page content is. There probably is no colDate class. Or maybe it is created dynamically using Javascript, in which case you either have to run JS or see if you can find the API page is using.